# How discover nearest's peers using JXTA?

Tags: p2p, jxta

I have a p2p network using JXTA protocol.
Is it possible discover what peers are nearest a specific peer?

tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a new studier of the jxse2.6,for your problem, i think you should make a discover of the peer advertisement.TheDiscoveryService.getRemoteAdvertisements(null, peer,
                    null, null, 0, new Edge_Maxime_The_Socializer()),and make a linster to   show the peer information.